# time duration from multiple time stamps within a set using Tableau

Tags: timestamp, duration, tableau-api

I have time stamp data that I would to find the total duration for within each set. I have a Date+Time column that has the following:

```
10/25/2013  12:10:46 PM
10/25/2013  12:10:47 PM
10/25/2013  12:10:55 PM
10/25/2013  12:10:59 PM
```

I want a calculation that will give me the total duration as follows: 00:00:13

Since from start to finish the total time was 13 seconds.

But each set may have 1 time stamp, or 100 time stamps.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATEDIFF('second',MIN(timestamp),MAX(timestamp))
```

Assuming your field is called "timestamp"